# python screenscraping opsview - avoid javascript on a dated headless server

Tags: javascript, python, opsview

I want to access an url in python, which basically returns csv data. The problem is it is behind a login page which requires javascript (it does not do anything usefull on the login page, its just there to make sure you have javascript for the subsequent pages). I have been doing this successfully on my dev machine (a fedora desktop) with ghost. Now the problem is, the production machine is a headless centos 6.2 machine (old software). So my quest to get ghost running there got me into dependency and backporting hell (I gave up when trying to backport qt ...).

I tried using mechanize, but that got rejected by the login page because there is no javascript enabled ...

So I was wondering what my options are:

- Can I somehow fool the site into thinking I can do javascript, using mechanize? (since the javascript does not do anything usefull for me)
- Are there any python screen scraping tools that can do javascript but won't require a display and work on centos 6.2 without lots of backporting?

Here is the javascript on the login page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var fname = window.self.name || '';
    var shash = window.self.location.hash || '';
    if ( fname == "foobar_frame" && shash.indexOf("login-reload") < 0 ) {
        window.parent.location.replace(window.parent.location.href +'#login-reload');
        window.parent.location.reload();
    }
  </script>
<div id='login_form_div'>
... html login form - I can handle that ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.login_form.login_username.focus();

... more javascript embedding social media stuff - i guess unrelated

</script>
```

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: pls login from browser. inspect the post url and variable. then do the same action in mechanize. may be i can provide answer if u give the url

Comment: Not sure, but [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) seems to have a binary linux build for centos 5.8+, maybe this doesn't have the dependencies of ghost.py?

Comment: It is our local opsview installation. @messifan your comment made me research further, and I found that there is a rest api for logging in and receiving and auth token (http://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview-core:restapi). I will try and use that - I will post my solution if I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got around the javascript requirement. The site I try to access is an opsview installation. Opsview is a commercial version of nagios - and offers a [rest api](http://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview-core:restapi), which allows you to retrieve a one_time_token, which is valid to log into the web user interface. So I managed to authenticate without javascript, and then used that token to query the url I was interested in:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mechanize
import json

username = 'foobar'
password = 'password'

# in my application, this urls gets composed so that I can choose my parameters
url = 'http://opsview.acme.org/cgi-bin/avail.cgi?show_log_entries=&host=all&timeperiod=custom&smon=07&sday=1&syear=2014&shour=0&smin=0&ssec=0&emon=08&eday=1&eyear=2014&ehour=24&emin=0&esec=0&rpttimeperiod=24x7&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestateretention=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&includesoftstates=no&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&backtrack=4&csvoutput='
# the trick is to include the parameter "include_one_time_token=1"
login_rest_url = 'http://opsview.acme.org/rest/login?include_one_time_token=1'
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots( False )
# generate one time token via rest api for logging into web user interface.
auth_data = {'username':username, 'password':password}
auth_data_encoded = json.dumps(auth_data)
browser.open(mechanize.Request(login_rest_url, data=auth_data_encoded, headers={"Content-type":"application/json"}))
one_time_token = json.loads(browser.response().get_data())['one_time_token']

# now authenticate to the web interface and retrieve information
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2'), ]
auth_url = 'http://opsview.acme.org/login?login_username=' + username + '&one_time_token=' + one_time_token
browser.open(auth_url)
browser.open(url)
print browser.response().get_data()
```